# Regular Expression match all sentence between two symbols on vim?

Tags: regex, vim

Hi this is my text file lines:

````
\```cpp
     addPart: partTemplate named: partName
     partCatalog at: partName put: partTemplate
```
````

i need to fetch all the sentence between ```cpp and ```.

I tried to write the following regex ```` :%s/```cpp\n\(.*\n\)*```//gc ```` but its matching all the lines in the file. Kindly any one help me to solve the problem. Thank is advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the outer `*` (the one repeating `\(.*\n\)`) is greedy (matches as many as possible).
Use `{-}` instead to match as few as possible :

````
:%s/```cpp\n\(.*\n\)\{-}```//gc
````

Comment: can you do one more help, same expression in converted in python regular expression, but the expression is not supporting {-}. modified expression is '```cpp\n(.*\n){-}' kindly help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

````
```cpp\n(([^\n]*\n)*)```
````

the first (1 not 0) group will match

```
     addPart: partTemplate named: partName
     partCatalog at: partName put: partTemplate
```